# How do I make sure that a file is not branchable across different projects in UCM?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

How do I make sure that a file is not branchable across different projects in UCM ?

It should always be picked from `/main/LATEST/` for all the parallel projects

Answer (score 0):

An UCM view is always built from the configuration of a stream, and, as a result, always select files based on the LATEST of the stream associated branch.

That being said, nothing prevent you to edit the config spec of a view, and add *at the beginning* of the config spec the rule:

```
element path/to/file /main/LATEST
```

But that will be valid only for one view, not for "all parallel projects".

A more generic approach would be at least to lock the file with [`cleartool lock`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lslock.htm).

That way, if you attempt to checkout the file in any view, it won't create a branch.
If that file was never checked out in any branch other than `/main`, then you are sure, by locking the file, that any UCM view would select it at `/main/LATEST`.

Answer (score 0):

@VonC, that's one way to do it... But the configspec change you mention would be overwritten the next time the stream is rebased. Everything depends on the component architecture of these projects, but there are a couple of other ways:

1. You can move the file to a non-modifiable component, if it's not in one already. If it's a shared file that noone should modify, then in a pure UCM environment, it logically would belong in a shared non-modifiable component.
2. If the file is in a non-UCM VOB, you can add the appropriate "element ... -nocheckout" lines to the view configspec after the "end ucm" line. These WILL be preserved in rebases. You will likely need additional "element" lines to make the file visible.

`element /vobtag/path/to/file /main/LATEST -nocheckout
element /vobtag/... /main/LATEST`

The order is significant as the view configpec is processed in order. So, if the -nocheckout line is AFTER the "element /vobtag/... /main/LATEST" line, it will be ignored and you'll be able to check out the file.